# NSDictionary; trouble getting values

Tags: ios, json, nsdictionary

this I the JSON file I am using for my dictionary:

```
{

    "Reports": {
        "Title of sheet": {
            "id": "1",
            "active": "0",
            "title": "Title of sheet",
            "date": "October 22, 2012",
            "description": "description",
            "ext": "DOCX",
            "fortest": "Tuesday, October 23",
            "subject": "Budget",
            "author": "xxxxxxxxxx",
            "email": "xxxxx@gmail.com"
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I am using to turn this into a dictionary (after I do a Request)

```
self.tableDataSource = [NSMutableArray array];

 for (NSString *key in object.allKeys) // object is your root NSDictionary
    {
        NSDictionary *subDict = [object valueForKey:key];
        //create a new dictionary with two values - one for the key and one for the value.
        NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [newDict setValue:subDict forKey:@"value"];
        [newDict setValue:key forKey:@"key"];
        [self.tableDataSource addObject:newDict];
    }
```

This generates an output of this:

```
(
        {
        key = Reports;
        value =         {
            "Sheet Title" =             {
                    active = 0;
                    author = "xxx xxxxxx";
                    date = "October 22, 2012";
                    description = "Description";
                    dl = "9 downloads";
                    email = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
                    ext = DOCX;
                    fortest= "Tuesday, October 23";
                    id = 1;
                    subject = Budget;
                    title = "Sheet title";
            };
        };
    }
)
```

Here's my question... How do I change the "title of sheet" to info = like I did with reports (key) and value?  The reports array would contain many more entries all with different "Title of sheet" arrays in side of it.  I don't want to be specific and call the array by name, cause there will always be arrays added to my json.  Please help, thanks!

P.S. I have tried fidling with the for loop, but to no avail...

---

Edit: I want something like this:

```
(
        {
        key = Reports;
        value =         {
            info =             {
                active = 0;
                author = "xxx xxxxxx";
                date = "October 22, 2012";
                description = "Description";
                dl = "9 downloads";
                email = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
                ext = DOCX;
                fortest = "Tuesday, October 23";
                id = 1;
                subject = Budget;
                title = "Sheet title";
            };
        };
    }
)
```

---

EDIT 2:

Got it!  I finally found the answer through a rather creative solution.  I basically converted my NSDictionary into an NSArray and was switching between the two, if that makes sense... I'll post some code when I get home

Comment: Any reason why you're not using http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html ?

Comment: @AJak I do for the request, but not for this...

Comment: @user1789040, So basically what you need is `subDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[subDict valueForKey:[[subDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]] forKey:@"Info"];`. Just add it after the line `NSDictionary *subDict = [object valueForKey:key];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your problem, add `subDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[subDict valueForKey:[[subDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]] forKey:@"info"];` to the method. Just add it after the line `NSDictionary *subDict = [object valueForKey:key];`

For eg:-

```
 self.tableDataSource = [NSMutableArray array];

 for (NSString *key in object.allKeys) // object is your root NSDictionary
    {
        NSDictionary *subDict = [object valueForKey:key];
        subDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[subDict valueForKey:[[subDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]] forKey:@"info"];
        //create a new dictionary with two values - one for the key and one for the value.
        NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [newDict setValue:subDict forKey:@"value"];
        [newDict setValue:key forKey:@"key"];
        [self.tableDataSource addObject:newDict];
    }
```

That should print,

```
(
        {
        key = Reports;
        value =         {
            info =             {
                active = 0;
                author = "xxx xxxxxx";
                date = "October 22, 2012";
                description = "Description";
                dl = "9 downloads";
                email = "xxxxxxx@gmail.com";
                ext = DOCX;
                fortest = "Tuesday, October 23";
                id = 1;
                subject = Budget;
                title = "Sheet title";
            };
        };
    }
)
```

**Update:**
As per the comment below, you need to use `subDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[subDict valueForKey:[[subDict allKeys] objectAtIndex:i]] forKey:@"info"];` in another loop to get all subarrays. Modify this line according to your requirement.